Hibernate Session Factory config to enable local transaction (no xa)
I have an application where we already have xa transaction enabled through atomikos lib however I want to configure local transaction. At a time only 1 transaction type will be enabled which will be controlled through spring profile. I am trying to configure hibernate session factory thru java class and this originally had atomikos factory classes but I want to conditionally configure same for local transactions.
try {
                // Start the configuration
                this.hibernateConfiguration = loadHibernateConfiguration(HIBERNATE_CONFIG_FILE);
                // commented for local transaction
//this.hibernateConfiguration.setProperty(HIBERNATE_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_LOOKUP_CLASS_NAME, //IMHibernateJtaTransactionManagerProvider.class.getName());
                this.hibernateConfiguration.setProperty(HIBERNATE_CONNECTION_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME, IMHibernateConnectionProvider.class.getName());
                if (Utility.isPostgresSQL()) {
                    this.hibernateConfiguration.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT, PostgreSQLDialect.class.getName());
                    this.hibernateConfiguration.setProperty(HIBERNATE_CONNECTION_DRIVER_CLASS, "org.postgresql.Driver");
                } else {
                    this.hibernateConfiguration.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT, Oracle10gDialect.class.getName());
                    this.hibernateConfiguration.setProperty(HIBERNATE_CONNECTION_DRIVER_CLASS, "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                }
//added jdbc transaction factory and commented atomikos one
this.hibernateConfiguration.setProperty(HIBERNATE_TRANSACTION_FACTORY_CLASS, JDBCTransactionFactory.class.getName());
                
                //this.hibernateConfiguration.setProperty(HIBERNATE_TRANSACTION_FACTORY_CLASS, //AtomikosJTATransactionFactory.class.getName());
                // Build the factory from the configuration
                this.hibernateSessionFactory = this.hibernateConfiguration.buildSessionFactory();

                // Set the spring boot session factory into the legacy InitSessionFactory
                InitSessionFactory.setInstance(this.hibernateSessionFactory, this.hibernateConfiguration);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new HibernateException("Could not initialize the Hibernate configuration", e);
            }

while debugging i do not get transaction manager object populated while configuring hibernate session factory. Can someone help me on this? How should do this if this is not required for local transactions.
